# Dynamic Wrapper in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm looking to create a dynamic wrapper class that exposes the API calls from a provided object using data in the object.

Statically it looks like this:

```
 class Concrete:
     def __init__(self, data):
       self.data = data

     def print_data(self):
         print(self.data)


 class Wrapper:
     '''
     One day this will wrap a variety of objects. But today
     it can only handle Concrete objects.
     '''
     def wrap_it(self, concrete):
         self.cco = concrete  # concreteobject=cco

     def print_data(self):
         self.cco.print_data()


 cco = Concrete(5)
 wcco = Wrapper()
 wcco.wrap_it(cco)
 wcco.print_data()
```

Produces

```
 5
```

I'd like to figure out how to do the same thing but make
`wrap_it` dynamic. It should search the concrete object
find the functions, and create functions of the same name
that call the same function in the concrete object.

I imagine that the solution involves `inspect.signature` or
at least some use of `*args` and `**kwargs`, but I've not seen
an example on how to put all this together.

Comment: What's the point of cloning the functions from one object to another? You might as well use the original object directly instead of the wrapper. Could you come up with an example that explains why you want to do this? The solution might vary depending on what exactly you're doing.

Comment: There are design needs to do this.

Comment: That doesn't even begin to answer my question. Like I said, the details might be important.

Comment: I really can't go into the details on it, other than to say that the wrapping solution above is what Is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [dir()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir) function to get the attributes of the given object, check if they are callable and assign them to your wrapper, like this:

```
 class Wrapper:
     def wrap_it(self, objToWrap):
         for attr in dir(objToWrap):
             if not attr.startswith('__') and callable(getattr(objToWrap, attr)):
                 exec('self.%s = objToWrap.%s' % (attr, attr))
```

And now, for testing.

```
>>> cco = Concrete(5)
>>> wcco = Wrapper()
>>> wcco.wrap_it(cco)
>>> wcco.print_data()
5
```

Comment: Note that this just creates **aliases** to original methods, and not wrapper methods. This may make perfectly sense or not, depending of what the OP intention is.

Comment: I think the alias approach matches my original need as it is the same as calling the function in the wrappedObject, right?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`__getattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) magic method to hook getting undefined attributes, and forward them to the concrete object:

```
class DynamicWrapper():
    def wrap_it(self, concrete):
        self.cco = concrete

    def __getattr__(self, k):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            print(f'DynamicWrapper calling {k} with args {args} {kwargs}')
            return getattr(self.cco, k)(*args, **kwargs)

        if hasattr(self.cco, k):
            return wrapper
        else:
            raise AttributeError(f'No such field/method: {k}')

cco = Concrete(5)
dwcco = DynamicWrapper()
dwcco.wrap_it(cco)
dwcco.print_data()
```

Comment: For special method names you probably have to implement `__getattribute__` instead of `__getattr__` which is a bit trickier to get to work correcrtly, because that will shadow existing attributes (such as `wrap_it`) so you have to provide a special case for that, and also, `self.cco` would generate an infinite recursion error, so you have to change that with `object.__getattribute__(self, 'cco')`. In short, you must know what you are doing very well if you chose to go this way.

Comment: Python3 doc says: "In addition to bypassing any instance attributes in the interest of correctness, implicit special method lookup generally also bypasses the __getattribute__() method even of the object’s metaclass". It hasn't changed since Python2.